# Foreign key referring to more than one primary key values(from one table) - Oracle SQL PLUS

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am still a beginner in SQL and i'm facing an issue. hope you can help me.
I have a table called Department where it has an attribute DEPARTMENT_NO as its primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
 DEPARTMENT_NO INT NOT NULL,
 NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 LOCATION CHAR(15),
 PRIMARY KEY(DEPARTMENT_NO));
```

I have another table called Doctor where it has an attribute DNUM as a foreign key referring to DEPARTMENT_NO :

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR(
 DOCTOR_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 DNUM INT NOT NULL,
 NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 DOB DATE,
 SPECIALTY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 SALARY INT,
 CITY VARCHAR(15),
 STREET VARCHAR(15),
 START_DATE DATE,
 PRIMARY KEY(DOCTOR_ID))
 FOREIGN KEY(DNUM) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_NO));
```

A doctor can be working in one or two departments. So, if I have a doctor working in department 1 and 4 (the values for DNUM will include 1 and 4).

I initially chose the data type of DNUM to be INT(same as DEPARTMENT_NO data type). But INT is not ideal for multiple values.

What should the data type be? or what other solution i have if,for example, I run a query for returning the name of the doctors working in department 4.
The query should return all the names of doctors working in department 4(only) and the ones who work in multiple departments(including 4).

Thanks very much in advance and sorry for the long message.

Comment: If you want a doctor to be in multiple departments, then create a third, join table that links DEPARTMENT_NO, DOCTOR_ID, and remove DNUM from DOCTOR

Comment: Are you saying that if a doctor works in 2 departments, you want to show that on one row?

Comment: Since it's multi values attribute/field, you will need to create a separate table for the same.

Comment: Thanks all. my relation was designated as 1:N relation. But now i need to change it to N:M relation so i can create another relation that joins the two tables. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to represent a "many to many" relationship is via a "junction" (aka "link") table:

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR_DEPARTMENT (
    DOCTOR_ID INT REFERENCES DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID),
    DEPARTMENT_NO INT REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_NO),
    PRIMARY KEY (DOCTOR_ID, DEPARTMENT_NO)
);
```

Note the key on {DOCTOR_ID, DEPARTMENT_NO}, which ensures the same doctor cannot be connected to the same department twice.

It also implicitly creates a composite (aka. "concatenated") index on these fields in that order, which makes it very quick to find departments of a given doctor (via an index range scan). If you need to query in the opposite "direction" (for doctors of the given department), flip the order of fields. If you need both queries, then you'll need both indexes (i.e. you'll need to create one index explicitly).

Consider adding [ORGANIZATION INDEX](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) clause, if you need just one of these indexes.

Comment: Thank you. your answer was the most helpful. ill check the organization index.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional table called doctor_department

```
create table doctor_department
(doctor_id integer references doctor(doctor_id) not null,
 dnum integer references department(dnum) not null
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will change my relation from 1:N to N:M so i can create the additional table.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another table with relation to these 2 tables
Say,

```
Create table Dept_Doctors(
ID int not null,
DOCTOR_ID char(9) not null,
DEPARTMENT_NO INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPARTMENT_NO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_NO),
FOREIGN KEY(DOCTOR_ID) REFERENCES DOCTOR(DOCTOR_ID));
```

You can join the 3 tables and get the desired result.

Comment: I believe i don't need the ID attribute. only DOCTOR_ID AND DEPARTMENT_NO.
I will change my relation from 1:N to N:M so i can create the additional table. and add the additional references. Much appreciated.

Comment: there you go! the ID is just in case if you dont want to have a composite key :)

Comment: @BhupeshC Adding ID does not obviate the need for the composite key.